# Automator AppleScript action ignores input

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have an Automator workflow that returns a list, an `NSArray` of `NSString`s, in the example below "FN3", "VN3", "NN3", "organization", and "notCancelled" (sorry for the German, but I think the image is clear anyway).
This list is input to an AppleScript action, which for testing purposes simply returns the input.  This AppleScript action **does not** ignore the input (this is indicated by the link between both actions).
Strangely, the output is an empty list:
[image]
What am I doing wrongly?

**UPDATE:**

I just realized the following:
When I use my own Obj-C action as input to the AppleScript action, the log file says between the end of my action, and the begin of the AppleScript action (translated): "Conversion of files/folders to files/folders terminated".
When I replace my own Obj-C action by a standard "Ask for text" action, everything works fine, and the log message before the AppleScript action says (translated): "Conversion of text to text terminated".
So, apparently, my Obj-C action returns something in the wrong format. What is the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
My Obj-C action had in its Info.plist a wrong output type specified. By default, it was:

[image]

For this reason, a conversion action tried to convert paths (which the action does not provide) to an appropriate input for the AppleScript action.

The correct setting is (in my case):

[image]

With this setting, the AppleScript action correctly outputs the input strings.